# (PHP) How to pass the previous INCLUDE / REQUIRE calls into child files?

Tags: php, include, require, ob-get-contents

I'm creating my own Templating Script by using the `ob_get_contents()` as a core method. By using it, it can render out the other files, calling from the one single file.

Just like, lets assume we have 4 files:

- index.php
- header.html
- footer.html
- functions.php

`index.php` will call and render the contents of other files (2 html files here). By using the following codes:

```
//index.php
function render($file) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
    ob_start();
    include($file);
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
    }
}
echo render('header.html');
echo render('footer.html');
```

But (for example) when `header.html` contains a call `include('functions.php')`, the included file (functions.php) can't be used again in `footer.html`. I mean, i have to make a include again in `footer.html`. So here, the line `include('functions.php')` have to be containing in both of files.

**How to `include()` a file without calling it again from child files**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `ob_start()` (Output buffering), you end up only with the output of the file, meaning file executed the output is returned by `ob_get_content()`. As only output is returned that other file is unaware of the includes.

So the answer is: you can't do it with output buffering. Or `include` your files before ob_start with `include_once`.

Comment: include my files before `ob_start` with `include_once`? Oh, so for my example, it is possible if i declare all necessary files with `include_once` at the top of `index.php`. So the childs won't need to declare again?

Comment: @4lvin Yes, of course it's possible. You can use `include_once` or `require_once` at the beginning and all your child files will see the included content.

Comment: WOw! Yeah! It is simple & incredible!! Cheers and thanks Arman P.

Answer (score 1):

That could work like something like this:

```
//index.php
function render($file) {
    if(!isset($GLOBALS['included'])) {
        $GLOBALS['included'] = array();
    } 

    if (!in_array($file, $GLOBALS['included']) && file_exists($file)) {
        ob_start();
        include($file);
        $content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        
        $GLOBALS['included'][] = $file;
        return $content;
    }
}

echo render('header.html');
echo render('footer.html');
```

Alternatively you could use [include_once](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) (`include_once $file;`)and PHP will do it for you.

Though I suggest you just make sure the file loading structure is in such shape that these events never happen.

Comment: Can i pls simply declare `include_once` one only time, at the very top of `index.php` file (before rendering the child files), instead of using your way `$GLOBALS`? For the knowledge please.

Comment: Yes you can. But even better is making sure a file is never included twice no matter what file is called.